# Hello word in Text is not displayed in the first flex.?

Tags: text, flexbox, jsx

i want to write heading in the first part of flex box but text is not visible.
here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const LogIn = () => {
    return (

      <View
        style={[
          styles.container,
          {
            // Try setting `flexDirection` to `"row"`.
            flexDirection: 'column',
            
          },
        ]}
        >
            
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#2D665F'}}> 
            <Text style = {styles.heading}> Hello </Text>
              </View>
           
         
            
            
            


            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
    
      </View>
    );
  };
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      
    },
    heading: {
        color: 'black',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        

    }
  });
  
  export default LogIn;

import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const LogIn = () => {
    return (

      <View
        style={[
          styles.container,
          {
            // Try setting `flexDirection` to `"row"`.
            flexDirection: 'column',
            
          },
        ]}
        >
            
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#2D665F'}}> 
# ** <Text style = {styles.heading}> Hello </Text>** the text in this tag is not displayed
              </View>
           
         
            
            
            


            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
    
      </View>
    );
  };
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      
    },
    heading: {
        color: 'black',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        

    }
  });
  
  export default LogIn;
```